# Reactive forms angular 2+- error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

La aplicación que estoy haciendo me falla aquí, les agradecería que me ayudasen ya que llevo dos semanas atascado, espero disculpen si son errores evidentes ya que tengo poca experiencia con esto

> **gusuarios.component.html** pagina

```
  <form method="POST"  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="enviar();" >
                    <div formGroupName="nombre">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                        <input 
                            formControlName="nombre"
                            placeholder="Nombre:" 
                            type="text" 
                            values="usuario.nombre" 
                            name="nombre"/>
                    </div>
                    <div formGroupName="id">
                        <input 
                            type="hidden" 
                            formControlName="id" 
                            values="usuario.id" 
                            name="id" 
                            value=0 />
                    </div>
                    <div formGroupName="apellidos">
                        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
                        <input 
                            placeholder="Apellidos:" 
                            type="text" 
                            values="usuario.apellidos" 
                            name="apellidos"
                            formControlName="apellidos"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div formGroupName="email">
                        <label for="email">Email(Login)</label>
                        <input 
                            placeholder="Email:" 
                            type="text" 
                            values="usuario.email" 
                            name="email"
                            formControlName="email"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div formGroupName="administrador">
                        <label for="administrador">Administrador</label>
                        <input 
                            type="checkbox" 
                            id="administrador" 
                            name="administrador" 
                            values="usuario.administrador"
                            formControlName="administrador"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" (click)="enviar()">Enviar!</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" (click)="volver()">Cancelar</a>
                </form>
```

**gusuarios.component.ts** Controlador

```
import { UsuariosService } from '../../services/usuarios.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Usuario } from '../../interfaces/usuario';
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gusuarios',
  templateUrl: './gusuarios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gusuarios.component.css']
  })

export class GUsuariosComponent implements OnInit {  
  title = 'Gestión de usuarios';
  form: FormGroup;
  static readonly clase:string = 'GUsuariosComponent';
  submitted = false;
  usuarios:any = [];
  usuario:Usuario = new Usuario();
  error:string = '';

  constructor(private usuariosService:UsuariosService, private router:Router,private fb: FormBuilder){
    console.log(GUsuariosComponent.clase+".constructor. entra");
    usuariosService.getUsuarios(this);
    console.log(GUsuariosComponent.clase+".constructor. sale");
  };
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(GUsuariosComponent.clase+".ngOnInit. entra");
    this.form= this.fb.group({
      nombre: ['', Validators.required],
      id:[0],
      apellidos: [''],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      administrador: [0, Validators.required]
    });
    console.log(GUsuariosComponent.clase+".ngOnInit. sale");
  }
  modificar(index:number){
    this.usuario=this.usuarios[index];
  }
  eliminar(index:number){
    this.usuariosService.eliminarUsuario(this, this.usuarios[index].id, index);
  }
  enviar(){
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.form.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    this.usuariosService.guardarUsuario(this, document);
  }
  volver(){
    this.router.navigate(['admin']);
  } 
    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.form.controls; }

}
```

Me muestra diferentes errores, ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Errores
.................................................................................
Error1
.................................................................................

```
     **ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'nombre -> nombre'
        at _throwError (forms.js:2144)
        at setUpControl (forms.js:2052)
        at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5281)
        at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5882)
        at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5803)
        at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22095)
        at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
        at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
        at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
        at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)**
```

.................................................................................
Error2
.................................................................................

```
       GUsuariosComponent.html:29 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'id -> id'
        at _throwError (forms.js:2144)
        at setUpControl (forms.js:2052)
        at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5281)
        at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:5882)
        at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5803)
        at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22095)
        at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
        at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
        at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
        at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
```

.................................................................................

Comment: Bueno, el problema que veo y que te marca en **GUsuariosComponent.html:6** es que tienes los `[formControlName]="nombre"`, `[formGroupName]="form"`, debes quitarle las llaves, quedaría así:  `formControlName="nombre"`, `formGroupName="form"`. Prueba con ello.

Comment: las he quitado y sale el mismo error

Comment: Lo he cambiado...

Comment: Lo edite.........................

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta en el archivo `gusuarios.component.html`, no tienes que poner la directiva `formGroupName` en las etiquetas `input`, porque ya tienes la directiva `formGroup` en `form`. Si quisieras poner un subgrupo en un formulario si que puedes utilizar la directiva `formGroupName`, pero no dentro de un `input`. Aquí hay mas información sobre [FormGroupName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName).

Quedaría así el archivo **HTML**:

```html
<form method="POST" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="enviar();" >
  <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
  <input 
      formControlName="nombre" 
      placeholder="Nombre:" 
      type="text" 
      values="usuario.nombre" 
      name="nombre"/>
  <input 
      type="hidden" 
      formControlName="id" 
      values="usuario.id" 
      name="id" 
      value=0 />
  <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
  <input 
      placeholder="Apellidos:" 
      type="text" 
      values="usuario.apellidos" 
      name="apellidos"
      formControlName="apellidos"/>
  <label for="email">Email(Login)</label>
  <input 
      placeholder="Email:" 
      type="text" 
      values="usuario.email" 
      name="email"
      formControlName="email"/>
  <label for="administrador">Administrador</label>
  <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      id="administrador" 
      name="administrador" 
      values="usuario.administrador"
      formControlName="administrador"/>
  <hr />
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" (click)="enviar()">Enviar!</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" (click)="volver()">Cancelar</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

He hecho cambios pero no me funciona bien la validacion

**gusuarios.component.ts**

```
import { UsuariosService } from '../../services/usuarios.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Usuario } from '../../interfaces/usuario';
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl} from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gusuarios',
  templateUrl: './gusuarios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gusuarios.component.css']
  })

export class GUsuariosComponent implements OnInit {  
  title = 'Gestión de usuarios';
  form: FormGroup;
  static readonly clase:string = 'GUsuariosComponent';
  submitted = false;
  usuarios:any = [];
  usuario:Usuario = new Usuario();
  error:string = '';

  constructor(private usuariosService:UsuariosService, private router:Router,private fb: FormBuilder){
    console.log(GUsuariosComponent.clase+".constructor. entra");
    usuariosService.getUsuarios(this);
    console.log(GUsuariosComponent.clase+".constructor. sale");
  };
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(GUsuariosComponent.clase+".ngOnInit. entra");
    this.form= this.fb.group({
      nombre :new FormGroup({
        'nombre': new FormControl('',Validators.required)
      }) ,
      id: new FormGroup({
        'id':new FormControl(0)
      }),
      apellidos: new FormGroup({ 
        'apellidos': new FormControl('')
      }),
      email: new FormGroup({
        'email': new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email]))
      }),
      password: new FormGroup({
        'password': new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]))
      }),
      administrador: new FormGroup({
         'administrador': new FormControl(0, Validators.required)
      })
    });
    console.log(GUsuariosComponent.clase+".ngOnInit. sale");
  }
  modificar(index:number){
    this.usuario=this.usuarios[index];
  }
  eliminar(index:number){
    this.usuariosService.eliminarUsuario(this, this.usuarios[index].id, index);
  }
  enviar(){

    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.form.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    this.usuariosService.guardarUsuario(this, document);
  }
  volver(){
    //console.log(nombre.errors);
    //this.router.navigate(['admin']);
  } 
    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.form.controls; }

}
```

**gusuario.component.html**

```
        <form method="POST"  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="enviar();" >
            <table width="100%" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                </td><td>
                    <div formGroupName="nombre">
                        <input 
                            class="form-control"
                            formControlName="nombre"
                            placeholder="Nombre:" 
                            type="text" 
                            value="usuario.nombre" 
                            name="nombre"/>
                    </div>
                    <div formGroupName="id">
                        <input 
                            type="hidden" 
                            formControlName="id" 
                            values="usuario.id" 
                            name="id" 
                            value=0 />
                    </div>
                    <label
                      [ngClass]="form.controls['nombre'].hasError('required')   ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success'"
                    >
                      <i class="material-icons">
                        {{ form.controls['nombre'].hasError('required')  ? 'cancel' :
                        'check_circle' }}
                      </i>
                      ¡El nombre es obligatorio!
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
                </td><td>
                    <div formGroupName="apellidos">
                        <input 
                            class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Apellidos:" 
                            type="text" 
                            value="usuario.apellidos" 
                            name="apellidos"
                            formControlName="apellidos"
                            />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="email">Email(Login)</label>
                </td><td>
                    <div formGroupName="email">
                        <input
                            class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Email:" 
                            type="text" 
                            value="usuario.email" 
                            name="email"
                            formControlName="email"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <label
                      [ngClass]="form.controls['email'].hasError('required') || form.controls['email'].hasError('email')  ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success'"
                    >
                      <i class="material-icons">
                        {{ form.controls['email'].hasError('required') ||
                        form.controls['email'].hasError('email') ? 'cancel' :
                        'check_circle' }}
                      </i>
                      ¡El email es incorrecto!
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="email">password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div formGroupName="password">
                        <input 
                            class="form-control"
                            placeholder="password:" 
                            type="password" 
                            value="usuario.password" 
                            name="password"
                            formControlName="password"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <label
                      [ngClass]="form.controls['password'].hasError('required') || form.controls['password'].hasError('minLength')  ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success'"
                    >
                      <i class="material-icons">
                        {{ form.controls['password'].hasError('required') ||
                        form.controls['password'].hasError('minLength') ? 'cancel' :
                        'check_circle' }}
                      </i>
                      ¡El password es incorrecto!
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="administrador">Administrador</label>
                </td><td>
                    <div formGroupName="administrador">
                        <input 
                            class="form-control"
                            type="checkbox" 
                            id="administrador" 
                            name="administrador" 
                            value="usuario.administrador"
                            formControlName="administrador"
                            />
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" (click)="enviar()" [disabled]="!form.valid">Enviar!</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" (click)="volver()">Cancelar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```